# Liveagent REST API

Tags: rest-api, liveagent

In the Request Headers (chapter 3) section of this salesforce doc: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest.pdf

Any idea on how to determine the X-LIVEAGENT-API-AFFINITY value?

Thanks!

Comment: It'd be nice if you copy the relevant info to your question of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I wanted to try using the "Messages" p. 14 and got stuck thinking what the X-LIVEAGENT-API-AFFINITY is. It's one of the Request headers for using "Messages" but i'm not sure what should be the value of it. I couldn't still find any related articles to get me going on reading so I tried asking here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the value of the affinityToken property of the SessionId response ([p. 31](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest.pdf#page=35)).

Answer (score 0):

Check the answer for the similar question [Affinity token missing from SessionId call](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24966/affinity-token-missing-from-sessionid-call)

Actually you will receive this token when you explicitly set the "X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY" parameter as "null" when you request a new session id through System/SessionId call.