# 400 Request is not a valid ChasitorInit - live agent rest api

Tags: rest-api, liveagent, salesforcemobilesdk-ios

Hi i'm trying to reach this endpoint with live agent rest api
https://d.la1-c1-frf.salesforceliveagent.com/chat/rest/Chasitor/ChasitorInit
Then got 400 Request is not a valid ChasitorInit
Here is my request body

```
{
    organizationId: "00D58000000OwMB",
    deploymentId: "57258000000L1mj",
    buttonId: "57358000000L24F",
    agentId: "005B0000000F3b2",
    doFallback: true,
    sessionId: "5a1c70ff-2ae0-4ddf-ae40-f685c30d5e8f",
    userAgent: "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.95 Safari/537.36",
    language; "en-US",
    screenResolution: "2560x1440"
    visitorName: "Halid"
    prechatDetails: [

    ],
    buttonOverrides: [
    ],
    receiveQueueUpdates: true,
    isPost: true
```

}
[image]

Im i doing anything wrong ??

Comment: SessionId expires in about 30 seconds, please check [this](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/120435/30686)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few things may be at play here.

1) Try passing the `X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY` value as null. This prevents the session expiry.

2) If you copied your JSON from the [online documentation example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.186.0.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_response_bodies.htm), it's wrong. You may want to use JSON lint to double check if your JSON is valid or not (I suspect this is most likely the issue in your case)

Unfortunately, the documentation still isn't updated but I've burnt my hands with this earlier and support was able to help resolve with the above suggestions. There's also another [thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24966/affinity-token-missing-from-sessionid-call) which lists these and a few other suggestions you may want to try.

Comment: Thanks @gaurav, as suggested the json is copied from the doc, therefore changed it to 
`{
    "sessionId": "8f1cfb18-fbd1-4487-90d9-e98c0a84e165",
    "organizationId": "00D58000000OwMB",
    "deploymentId": "57258000000L1mj",
    "buttonId": "57358000000L24F",

    "userAgent": "",
    "language": "en-US",
    "screenResolution": "1900x1080",
    "visitorName": "Test Visitor",
    "prechatDetails": [],
    "prechatEntities": [],
    "receiveQueueUpdates": true,
    "isPost": true
}`
It works !!

Comment: Great, happy to help!

Comment: I am getting "An error has occurred while processing your request. The salesforce.com support team has been notified of the problem. " I am trying with API version 37 @GauravKheterpal Did you face this issue anytime?