# C# Get SessionId returns affinity token empty ("")

Tags: api, rest, liveagent, c#, session-id

When im doing the GET request to get the affinityToken, its come empty

```
{"key":"b99d9a87-c7db-4f5a-a20d-9419bb2d0ad0!1549978665283!x6db6+hNaLzITCEq9EcjFLyKAjw=","id":"b99d9a87-c7db-4f5a-a20d-9419bb2d0ad0","clientPollTimeout":40,"affinityToken":""}
```

I set the two headers.

```
req.Headers["X-LIVEAGENT-API-VERSION"] = "34";

req.Headers["X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY"] = null;
```

I'm using C#

Why do I get an empty response?

Answer (score 0):

I found this previous question around a similar issue: [Affinity token missing from SessionId call](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/25098/102).

> To have the sessionId call return the affinity token, along with the X-LIVEAGENT-API-VERSION you also have to send the X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY parameter with the value explicitly stated as 'null'.

I suspect the problem might be around what concept of `null` they actually want here.

It looks like you are explicitly setting the `X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY` header to the C# version of null. Instead, try setting it to a string with the value null. E.g.

```
req.Headers["X-LIVEAGENT-AFFINITY"] = "null";
```

I suspect they are looking for that string in the header.